# Disappearing digits in output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    float i=22;
    float x= i/7;
    float y=x-3;
    std::cout << sizeof(i)<<"\t";
    std::cout<<y<<" "<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs the following:

```
8   0.142857  3.14286
```

How is this possible? Why is the output not `3.148257` ?

I tried to rationalize but couldn't understand it in the end. `float` should have a precision of 7 digits.

Comment: `cout` defaults to output 6 digits. See [setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/oaYWaMrMr

Comment: @Bop Is 0 not counted as a digit ?

Comment: if you add `std::cout<<std::cout.precision();` to your code, you will see that by default it's set up to output 6 significant digits. 3.148257 would be 7 digits, so it gets rounded to 3.14286

Comment: no, leading zeros aren't counted as [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)